# c, shrink allocated space from the beginning

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

Assume I have allocated space for an array with

```
double *array;
array=malloc(100*sizeof(double));
```

I do some processes and finally I don't need the first 10 elements any more, I tried this with `realloc`:

```
array=realloc(array+10, 90*sizeof(double));
```

but I get an invalid pointer error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./temp: realloc(): invalid pointer:...
```

How can I shrink an array from its beginning?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Only option would be to shift the active elements back to the beginning and then realloc off the end.  Or use some kind of active structure (like a linked list).

Comment: Thank you Grijesh Chauhan and H2CO3, I understood! My reference (King's C programming, a modern approach), said: "Although `realloc` doesn't require that `ptr` point to memory that's being used as an array, in practice it usually does." I interpreted this as a freedom in being able to do what I thought! Now I understand I can't! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, reallocating an array just in order to **shrink** it is not quite a good idea. If you do it a lot of times, it may potentially lead to memory fragmentation. Use `realloc()` to **extend** the array when necessary. (This won't prevent fragmentation either of course, but if you use `realloc()` less, that helps.)

---

That said, if you still want to shrink the array: as [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/realloc.html) (***which you have read before asking this question, amirite?***) says, you have to call `realloc()` on the pointer returned by `malloc()`. Not that pointer plus ten, not that pointer times Euler's constant, not that pointer minus the number of days in the current month, nothing else, just **that very same pointer.**

So you have to move the elements first, then reallocate the array. But that involves copying the elements to a temporary buffer like this:

```
double *tmp = malloc(90 * sizeof(*tmp));
memcpy(tmp, array, 90 * sizeof(*tmp));

double *guard = realloc(array, 90 * sizeof(*array));
if (!guard) {
    // realloc() failed
    abort(); // whatever
}

array = guard;
memcpy(array, tmp, 90 * sizeof(*tmp));
```

**So this isn't any better,** you could just `free()` the old array after copying its contents and assigning the newly obtained pointer to `array`.

Comment: And, just for completeness' sake, [The (most current edition of the) documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Read: [`void* realloc (void* ptr, size_t size);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/):

> **Reallocate memory block**
>
> Changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr.
>
> The function may move the memory block to a new location (whose
>   address is returned by the function).
>
> The content of the memory block is preserved up to the lesser of the
>   new and old sizes, even if the block is moved to a new location. If
>   the new size is larger, the value of the newly allocated portion is
>   indeterminate.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   `ptr`
>   *Pointer to a memory block previously allocated* with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.
>   Alternatively, this can be a null pointer, in which case a new block is allocated (as if `malloc` was called).

No you can't reallocate elements like this, `realloc` need an addressees that is returned by `malloc()`/`calloc()` functions

So what you can do is remove first 10 numbers from array, then call reallocate.

In many implementations a shrink-action call via `realloc()` result in the change of the reserved size in the heap and wouldn't move memory. (yes but memory management may move to fill fragmentation area).

Comment: Please don't post links to cplusplus.com for two reasons: 1. we are talking about C, not C++; 2. cplusplus.com is a horrible site, it contains all sort of inaccuracies. For C questions, link to The Open Group's official documentation, and for C++, probably en.cppreference.com is better.

Comment: @H2CO3 yes? Thanks correct suggestion. but most of the times I found it very helpful.

Comment: @Ggijesh Yes, and it may seem comprehensive and helpful, but unfortunately it's often just wrong. [Link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972076/why-is-the-cplusplus-website-bad)

Comment: And for completeness sake, links to The Open Group's official documentation: [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/), and [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).